# How to compare same keys values from different dict with percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Trying to compare same keys values from two different dict, If second dict values are bigger by 50% than first dict values then output should show different keys values only.

```
first={'a': '0.1000', 'b': '0.2000', 'c': '0.2400'}
second={'a': '0.1000', 'b': '0.3000', 'c': '0.5000'}
desired = {'c': '5000'} # c is 50% bigger from first dict value
```

below is my code:

```
print({k: v for k, v in second.items() if int(v) > int(first[k]) * 1.5})
```

but getting this error:
    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that both of the dictionaries have the exact same keys? I would run `print(any(True for x in second if x not in first))` and see what it says.

Comment: given the error mentions `float` and your code uses `int`, i highly suspect you didn't give us your real code...

Comment: Your code raises `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.1000'`. If you fix that by using `float` instead of `int`, you get`{'c': '0.5000'}`. I'm not sure how you want to turn that `'0.5000'` into `'5000'`, but, whether it's `v[2:]` or `str(int(float(v) * 10000))` or `v.split('.')[-1]` or whatever rule you want, just drop that rule in place of the first `v` and you're done.

Comment: Also, I have no idea how `'5000'` is supposed to be "50% bigger" than `0.5000`, or any of your other values, even after multiplying by 10000 or whatever it is you want to do. For example, it's 108.33…% bigger than `10000 * float(first['c'])`, which seems to be the closest thing that makes sense to what you're saying.

Comment: print(any(True for x in second if x not in first)) is giving new dict but sometimes it gives false, could this be because in my dict there is both float and int in its values? if sow how ti fix this problem ?

Comment: Please add needed code to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
desired={}

for k, v in first.items():
    if (float(second[k])) > (1.5*float(first[k])):
        desired[k] = v
```

Assuming that you have the same keys in first and second dictionaries.

Comment: Same: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Than it must be something with your environment or cells possibly if you are using Jupyter Notebooks.

Type:
print(type(first['a']))

and you'll see it can not be NoneType.

Comment: print(type(first['a'])) is giving <class 'str'>

Comment: Funny. Same here and it works. You are obviously not feeding the float() function with NoneType so I am now lost as to why you do not get the expected results.

Comment: and yesterday same code worked fine. today started to get this error though nothing is chnaged

Comment: Than go back to yesterday, i.e. reboot everything.

Comment: used numpy.float16 and its worked, looks like there were huge float numbers in the dict which changed and did not notice it

Answer (score -1):

You are not parsing it properly, `strip` the `"0."` as follows:

```
first={'a': '0.1000', 'b': '0.2000', 'c': '0.2400'}
second={'a': '0.1000', 'b': '0.3000', 'c': '0.5000'}
print({k: v.lstrip("0.") for k, v in second.items() if int(v.lstrip("0.")) > int(first[k].lstrip("0.")) * 1.5})
{'c': '5000'}
```